# Seperate binary digits to excel rows with python

Tags: python, excel

Actually I'm creating a list where I convert integer to binary digits with 8 bit representation and writing the binary to excel spreadsheet:

```
row = 3
for x in MyList:
    mybinary = bin(x)[2:].zfill(8)  
    ws.write(r,2,mybinary)
    row+=1
```

The result looks like:
[image]

What I would like to achieve is:
[image]

The bits should have the same order but just ordered over the 8 rows from right side.

Debug Info:

```
print(type(MyList))
<type 'list'>


print(type(x))
<type 'int'>
<type 'int'>
<type 'int'>
<type 'int'>
<type 'int'>
```

And the output of mybinary is so far OK (The binary string which is output in excel sheet) and correct converted

Any idea?

Comment: Can you attached your full code here? It is easy to give a solution.

Comment: I have added some debug info. I think the code before is not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for ind, val in enumerate(str(mybinary)):
    ws.write(r, ind + 2, val)
```

replacing your `ws.write(r,2,mybinary)` statement with above two lines will do your job.